# extract a random attribute and render in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

With a ruby function, one can extract a random value

```
first_random = ["alt_1", "alt_2", "alt_3", "alt_4", "alt_5", "alt_6"].sample
```

Class attributes are `alt_1, alt_2, alt_3, alt_4, alt_5, alt_6, name, created_at, updated_at`

These values represent attributes of a class.  They cannot be described within the array without the quotes to identify these as strings, AFAIK.  The goal is to invoke this random attribute in a view.  However,

```
@text.first_random
```

generates a method missing error as ruby is certainly passing along the quotes.

How can this be overcome?

Comment: You might want to paste some code showiong us how your class is setup. But just from glancing id say that It looks like the way your explaining this that the name of the attribute is `first_random`.

Can you please just post the entire class so I can reproduce the error.

Comment: updated.  There is a misunderstanding `first_random` is NOT an attribute. It is an instanciation of a random attribute of that class, from that list.

Comment: I see what you're doing now. 
I would try adding `@text.send(first_random.to_s)`

Comment: ...and you would be correct !  I've been searching for this concise manner to do this for yonks!

Comment: Thanks. If I make it an answer will you accept it?

Comment: certainly. 4321

Comment: take a look at this info on `method_missing` [https://www.leighhalliday.com/understanding-method-missing](https://www.leighhalliday.com/understanding-method-missing)

and on `.send()`

[https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try adding

`@text.send(first_random.to_sym)`

*edit: `.send()` will take a string or a symbol. I had written `.to_s` earlier but that was a mistake. I like to implicitly convert to a symbol when I use this method. Im not sure if there are performance benefits. Just as a matter of style.

Comment: To avoid calling private methods, you can use `public_send` instead of `send`.

Answer (score 5):

In Rails, you can access a model's attributes via its [`attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attributes) method, e.g.:

```
@text.attributes['alt_1']
```

To get a random attribute based on your code:

```
first_random = %w[alt_1 alt_2 alt_3 alt_4 alt_5 alt_6].sample

@text.attributes[first_random]
```